# Why avoid CGI for Python with LAMP hosting?

Tags: php, python, .htaccess, cgi

I have been using PHP for years. Lately I've come across numerous forum posts stating that **PHP is outdated**, that modern programming languages are easier, more secure, etc. etc.

So, I decided to **start learning Python**. Since I'm used to using PHP, I just started building pages by uploading an .htaccess file with:

```
addtype text/html py
addhandler cgi-script .py
```

Then, my sample pages look like:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
print "content-type: text/html\n\n"
print "html tags, more stuff, etc."
```

This works fine. But, I came across a comment in a post that said that **CGI isn't the best way to use Python**. Of course, it didn't mention what *is* the best way.

**Why is it that using CGI is not the best way to use Python? What is the alternative?**

Is there some **totally other way** to set up a simple Python site? Is there some completely different paradigm I should be looking at outside of .htaccess and .py files?

#### Related

- [Pros and Cons of different approaches to web programming in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43709/pros-and-cons-of-different-approaches-to-web-programming-in-python)
- [What’s a good lightweight Python MVC framework?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68986/whats-a-good-lightweight-python-mvc-framework) (esp., [@Kevin Dangoor's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68986/whats-a-good-lightweight-python-mvc-framework/83263#83263))
- [How do I use python for web development without relying on a framework?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/596729/how-do-i-use-python-for-web-development-without-relying-on-a-framework)
- [Python Web Framework - Not App Framework or CMS Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/490210/python-web-framework-not-app-framework-or-cms-framework)
- [Python web programming](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/581038/python-web-programming)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Classic CGI isn't the best way to use anything at all. With classic CGI server has to **spawn a new process for every request**.

As for Python, you have few alternatives:

- [`mod_wsgi`](http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/)
- [`mod_python`](http://modpython.org/)
- [fastcgi](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-fastcgi)
- standalone Python web server ([built-in](http://docs.python.org/library/simplehttpserver.html), [CherryPy](http://www.cherrypy.org/), [Tracd](http://trac.edgewall.org/wiki/TracStandalone) )
- standalone Python web server on non-standard port and [`mod_proxy`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy.html) in Apache

Comment: I wouldn't recommend simplehttpserver for an actual production webapp.  It's more for having an embedded webserver in other applications.  As a replacement, might I recommend cherrypy - http://cherrypy.org/ ?

Comment: One could also note that you can use a different, smaller proxying webserver like nginx or lighttpd in place of apache.

Comment: For shared hosting service users -- and that probably means most readers of this post -- this constraint isn't really relevant because such shared hosting configurations invariably use UID/GID access control to separate individual user accounts and therefor always spawn a separate process for *any* scripted URI -- PHP, Python of whatever.

Answer (score 5):

> Why is it that using CGI is not the best way to use Python?

I will stick up for CGI a little. It's good for development environments.

It's simple to wire up and you don't have to worry about module reloading problems. Naturally performance is terrible, but for dev you don't care.

Of course you should really be writing to the WSGI interface rather than CGI directly. You can then deploy through CGI using:

```
wsgiref.handlers.CGIHandler().run(application)
```

and use the same application object to deploy through mod_wsgi other whatever other WSGI server you prefer in the production environment where speed matters (and the testing environment where you want it to be as close to production as possible).

Answer (score 3):

[**mod_wsgi**](http://code.djangoproject.com/wiki/django_apache_and_mod_wsgi) is the proper alternative. It is preferable over CGI in almost all aspects.

Comment: Great if you control your own LAMP stack on a VM or dedicated box, but can you identify a shared hosting provider that actually loads and enables `mod_wsgi`?

Comment: Nope. But no one explicitly asked about shared hosting.

Comment: I agree Yuval, but given that the significant majority of hosting users use a shared hosting account, I assume including the original poster (since he's doing this via `.htaccess` files and not his vhost config).  Isn't it just as flawed to assume that the original poster has root access to his web service.  Perhaps a caveat "CGI in almost all aspects, except of course in the most common case of a shared hosting account where you won't be able to use it" ;-P

Answer (score 3):

Really it's just an efficiency thing - CGI spawns an entire new process for every request, which is quite heavyweight for what it does.

PHP can be run through CGI as well, but mod_php embeds the interpreter within apache.
There's a [mod_python](http://www.modpython.org/) which does the same job, and [mod_wsgi](http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/) as Yuval says.

Answer (score 2):

Aside from the suggestions others make, you should really consider using a framework of some kind.  You can and should be using [FastCGI](http://www.fastcgi.com/), mod_python, or mod_wsgi, but they weren't really intended for you to write code directly against.  Might I suggest one of the following?

- [django](http://www.djangoproject.com) (my favorite for practical applications)
- [pylons](http://pylonshq.com/)
- [cherrypy](http://www.cherrypy.org/)  (my favorite for not-so-practical applications)
- [web.py](http://webpy.org/)

Comment: +1: "some completely different paradigm I should be looking at outside of .htaccess and .py files"

Comment: I am learning Pylons at the same time, but it's nice to use a framework where I can also program in the underlying language.

Answer (score 2):

There is a page in the Python documentation that describes the [advantages and disadvantages of the various possibilities](http://docs.python.org/howto/webservers.html).

**mod_python**

> (…) These are the reasons why mod_python should be avoided when writing new programs.

**WSGI**

> The *Web Server Gateway Interface* or
>   WSGI for short is currently the best
>   possible way to Python web
>   programming. While it is great for
>   programmers writing frameworks, the
>   normal person does not need to get in
>   direct contact with it.

**FastCGI and stuff**

> These days, FastCGI is never used directly.

Comment: FastCGI is heavily used by shared hosting environments. I personally use PHP with FastCGI (using nginx instead of apache) for some stuff at home.

Comment: Note that the post says that FastCGI is never used *directly* (presumably in the context of Python).  This is pretty much consistent with my experience.

Comment: Actually that's what the documentation says.